# pip requirements.txt github repo django app

Tags: python, django, git, github, requirements.txt

I have [forked a repo on Github](https://github.com/eldamir/django-datatable-view) in order to make my own changes to it. I have submitted a pull request to the original repo, but while I wait, I would like to add my repo to my pip requirements.txt.

I've added the line like this:

```
[...]
-e git+https://github.com/eldamir/django-datatable-view.git#egg=datatableview
```

I then run `pip install -r requirements.txt`. The repo is downloaded. I try importing the module to make sure that it works:

```
python -c "import datatableview"
```

No errors. All is well. However, as this is a django app, I need to add it to my `INSTALLED_APPS`. Doing so yields no error, but the template loader does not seem to find the templates of the app. This worked fine when I did `pip install django-datatable-view`. I assume my forked `setup.py` file works just as well as the original one. So what is different here?

**Update1**

The MANIFEST.in file contains

```
include README.md
include requirements.txt
recursive-include datatableview/static *
recursive-include datatableview/templates *
```

I don't know much about the purpose of this file, but I suppose this is the one that collects files and put them into place. The templates folder is recursively included

Comment: Does pip put the missing template on your hard disk? Is the file actually physically present on your hard drive or not?

Comment: All the files are there. The templates are where I'd expect, in `env/src/datatableview/datatableview/templates/datatableview/`.

Comment: Hmm... for some weird reason, after a reboot, it seems to work

Answer (score 0):

Check your virtualenv `src` folder or similar where the package is installed to confirm that it actually installs all files, particularly the missing file.

Most likely it is packakging problem caused by missing MANIFEST.in file in the package and needs a bug fix.

Add missing filenames, relevant tracebacks, etc. to the question if it doesn't solve the issue.